# Sometime getting error while downloading the Excel output file

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my ASP.NET web application, downloading an output Excel file is sometimes causing an error. In such cases, the file is not downloaded correctly, but instead it's downloaded with XML data, or I get an error:

> Could not download the file error

Clicking "retry" enough time makes it work in IE browser.

**Note:** the output file is downloaded from IIS server where the application was hosted. i.e. `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWebApplication\OutputFiles`

I am using the following code to download the file:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "Application/txt";

string strFileName = (((ASPxButton)sender).CommandArgument).ToString();
string FilePath = MapPath("~/OutputFiles/" + jobNumber + "/" + strFileName);

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFileName);
Response.TransmitFile(FilePath);

Response.Flush();
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
Response.Close();
```

The above code is working fine but I don't know why there is an error some times. How to solve this issue? Please advice me.

**UPDATE:** "***The file could not download***" error is occurred by following scenario, 
Two users, download the output files from different path in parallel. I.e (In IE browser) user1 click the download & save button, at the same time user2 click the download & save button (both user download the different files from different path in IIS directory). which means, One user try to download a file while another file is already downloading by another user.

How can fix this issue while parallel download?

Thanks,
Kavin.S

Comment: Does the error depend on the file size ?

Comment: hi @tchrikch, May be, because i'm getting this errors while downloading more than 10 MB size of file.

Comment: **Update:**
@tchrikch, it happens on all file sizes and random tries.

Comment: Hi all, anyone help me to solve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: **UPDATE:**

**_"The file could not download"_** error is occurred by following scenario,

Two users, download the output files from different path in parallel. I.e (In IE browser) user1 click the download & save button, at the same time user2 click the download & save button (both user download the different files from different path in IIS directory).

How can fix this issue while parallel download?

Thanks, Kavin.S

Answer (score 1):

In your system.web node of your web.config alter or add the following where xxxx is the appropriate file size in KB.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxxx">
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply @kyle, I have already given the following configuration,
`<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" requestValidationMode="4.0" executionTimeout="3600" requestLengthDiskThreshold="99999" targetFramework="4.5" />`